# Different Bytes Received under windows and linux when running same .NET 6 application connected to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, network-programming, prometheus, .net-6.0, system.data.sqlclient

During the analysis of some Prometheus metrics I found an interesting difference in the received network traffic whether an .NET 6 application runs under Linux (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) or Windows (Windows Server 2019 Standard) fetching data from a Microsoft SQL Server.

When the application runs under windows it seems as if the bytes transferred in the response from the SQL Server are not included in the prometheus metric `system_net_sockets_bytes_received`. In an example test I had a value of 2.566 bytes here.
If I compile the same application to Linux and do the same test, this metric has 91.470.730 bytes.

Has someone an explanation for this? I could not find any information for this behaviour in the web. The SQL Server tells me in `sys.dm_exec_connections` that both connections use TCP (column net_transport).

Here some code snippets to recreate the scenario. I use the nuget packages prometheus-net (8.0.1), prometheus-net.AspNetCore (8.0.1) and System.Data.SqlClient (4.7.0).

Program.cs:

```
using Prometheus;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
}
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseHttpMetrics();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapMetrics();
});

app.Run();
```

Test-Logic:

```
public void TestReceviedBytes()
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING");
    conn.Open();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"YOUR SELECT COMMAND", conn);

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", reader["Id"]));
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Fetched run {i}");
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

Comment: Your second metric (91,470,730 bytes) seems more correct. 100,000 iterations of any command aren't going to be achieved using only 2,566 bytes of network traffic.